# React hooks performance dillema

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Which would be better in terms of performance
consider the following:
Component `A`: uses the theme hook
Component `B` takes props from `A`,

Would it be more performant to use the theme hook in component `B` or just pass it from component `A` to `B` as a prop?

Also, if passing the value as a hook, what if we just add more components, would it still be the same, let's say we add `A` ->  `B` -> `C` -> `D`

Comment: I recommend reading [this](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: Good insight. Thanks. I'm not trying to fix a bottle neck, just trying to see if i'm coding at the best standards.

Comment: Given the info provided here, it seems too vague to say. Often, optimizing performance, assuming that's even determinable here, drastically reduces maintainability or ease of coding, so something like "best standards" is a pretty vague zone to be in. Everything is tradeoffs and it typically comes down to a multitude of details about your particular use case as far as what to prioritize.

Comment: The difference of time will be minimal. Passing props will make your code more illegible than using the theme HOC for the component: export default withTheme(A) (for example) is easier to read than making a "maze" of props. I recommend you to forget about performance in this type of situations... the difference of time here is atomic.